# How to calculate the integral of exponential of complex exponential?

Tags: integration

How to express
$$\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}e^{c \cdot e^{j\omega}}d\omega$$ in closed form, where $c$ is a constant?
Should it be some Bessel function?

Comment: Is $j = \sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: if you don't like the Cauchy integral theorem, re-prove it : show that $\frac{\partial}{\partial c} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{c e^{i \omega}} d\omega = 0$
so $\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{c e^{i \omega`}} d\omega = \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{0} d\omega = 2 \pi$

Comment: @user1952009 How did you determine that the derivative is $0$.  It is indeed $0$.  But what methodology did you use here?  Was it $e^{i\omega}e^{ce^{i\omega}}=\frac{1}{ic}\frac{\partial e^{ce^{i\omega}}}{\partial \omega}$?

Comment: @Dr. MV : in general with $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k z^k$ for $|z| \le C$ you can write that for $r < C$ : $$\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(r e^{i\omega}) d \omega = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i \omega} f'(r e^{i\omega}) d \omega = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k \, c_k \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i \omega k} d\omega = 0$$ so exploiting analyticity instead of holomorphy as you did (not so different finally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=e^{i \omega}$ (sorry, I use $i$) and the integral becomes

$$-i \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z} e^{c z}$$

which is $2 \pi$ by Cauchy's Integral theorem.

Comment: Thanks, I also found that this can be proven by Taylor expansion